# jqgrid onSortCol return 'stop' not able to stop client side sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I am having issues with the onSortCol event of the jqgrid.

I am trying to disable client side sorting and handle it on the server side.
due to contraints i have to use datatype as local and not json.

I can see the server side call being made and the results fetched and getting displayed 
in the ui screen. however i am not able to stop client side sorting from happening .

return 'stop' is not able to stop the jqgrid from performing the sorting on the newly returned data.

can someone let me know how to stop client side sorting from happening here?

here is the code inside the onSortCol function:

// populate data using async call

```
     onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {            

        that.store.find("oldcontact",{page:page,pagesize:pageSize,columnName:index,sortOrder:sortOrder}).then(function(data){


                          grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');


                              grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: data});

                              grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                              return 'stop';


                      });

                 } ,
```

Answer (score 2):

found the solution for my problem..

Just define the sorttype to return a constant value will disable the client side sorting.

this did the trick for me:

```
     colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', key: true, width:70,sorttype:"int"},
                {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:90,sorttype: function () {
                                                                  return 1; // any constant value
                                                              }},
                {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100,sorttype: function () {
                                                                 return 1; // any constant value
                                                             }}

            ]
```

I continue to handle the custom sorting inside the onSortCol as posted above in my question....

Answer (score 0):

Client side sorting can be disabled by specifying "sortable:false" when declaring columns. refer below snippet.

```
//your grid.
jQuery('#myJqGrid');
//Definition of a colModel
{name:'ColumnName', index:'name', sortable:false, align:'left', edittype:'text'}
```

Comment: The problem with specifying "sortable:false" is the on clicking the columns no event is triggered by the grid and hence the onSolCol event doesnt get fired. I am handling sorting server side in the code above and want the event to get triggered. the issue in the code once jqgrid  gets the result from the server above it tries to sort it(which defeats the purpose of sorting server side). I just want jqgrid not to do so. I have seen in some posts return 'stop' does that but in my above code  it is not working.